# add SPI wthernet connection , not working - how can I check why?

Tags: pi-zero-w, spi, ethernet-port

I have added a spi ethernet tp my pi zero

connected it and added the needed files

> anyspi.dtbo , w5500.dtbo

added in config.txt

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=anyspi,spi0-0,dev="w5500",speed=30000000
dtoverlay=w5500
```

but I can't see it in ifconfig after reboot

all the connection are correct  and the device is powered on (I have 2 other pi zero with the same connection and it's working )

where can I see in the logs what is wrong?

```
Ehternet PINS    PI Pins
MI               21   
V                1 (3.3V)
G                6 (GND)
Int              22
CS               24
SCK              23
MO               19
```

everything is like it said in this guide

```
https://www.instructables.com/Add-a-WIZ850io-Wiznet-W5500-Network-Port-to-Your-R/
```

Thanks,

Comment: First thought is if it works on one Zero and not another then it's a cable or software issue.  First thing I would try is a copy of the SD card from a working Pi - that rules out hardware if it works...

Comment: I have try , took the SD from one an the connection is good . so it's not this